# One TableView implemented in several ViewControllers

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am looking for a way to create a TableView to show a list of posts on a social networking site. I want to place the exact same prototype table in several ViewControllers and based on the current ViewController, it will be populated with different information. Is there a way to do this with Storyboard? I assume that this is quite easy using only code, but I would like to drag and drop elements to create the prototype cell.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each view controller you should create a new table view. You could reuse table view cells by creating a custom nib cell and populating each table view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial on how to populate a table view with an rss feed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyrGnbzXpxk

You can then find the rss feed of each social media page that you want to include in each table view.